# Configure server to ignore NDRs to forged addresses/domains

Tags: email-server, spam, email-bounces, ndr

[AT&T's Blacklist site](http://rbl.att.net/cgi-bin/rbl/block_admin.cgi) suggests one option of correcting [mail server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_transfer_agent) issues is:

> Reconfigured server to ignore NDRs to forged addresses/domains

However, [NDR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non_delivery_report)s are returned to the sender by their own server's mail [daemon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daemon_(computing)). So, it seems that one's mail server could never [SPAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_spam) another mail server by sending NDRs.

Another indirect form of [spamming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spamming) is [backscatter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backscatter_(email)). Could this be what AT&T is referring to? If so, how could one go about securing (or confirming) their mail server to address this issue?

---

Current setup:

- [APF](https://www.rfxn.com/projects/advanced-policy-firewall/) blocking previously malicious IPs
- Rejecting mail from 4 [RBL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNSBL)s
- Rejecting SPAM via [SpamAssassin](http://spamassassin.apache.org/) SPAM score
- Rejecting SPAM via SpamAssassin domain policies
- Disabled catchalls for all client accounts
- Discarding (instead of bouncing) SpamAssasssin SPAM for large volume accounts
- Registered server on abuse networks of major mail hosts
- Monitoring RBLs for listing notices

Answer (score 2):

In short, to prevent backscatter you configure your mailserver to reject an undesired e-mail message **during** the SMTP transaction, rather than accepting the message first and then rejecting it at a latter stage.
By not accepting the message it remains the responsibility of the sending mailserver and it is not your mailserver but rather the sending mailserver that has to generate the Non-Delivery Report.

Alternatively you configure your mailserver/spamfilter/antivirus software to not reject undesired mail, bit to simply discard it silently or quarantaine it.